# Duplication issues with three SSD Windows freezing questions

Tags: discussion

I noticed three similar questions that are a little outside my ballywick and am hoping someone can recommend what, if anything, should be done with them.

- [SSD causes my Windows 7 installation to freeze](https://superuser.com/questions/365493/ssd-causes-my-windows-7-installation-to-freeze)
- [Solid State Drive occasionally freezes for a minute while OS is beach balling](https://superuser.com/questions/483125/solid-state-drive-occasionally-freezes-for-a-minute-while-os-is-beach-balling/880515#880515)
- [Using an SSD with no AHCI ICH7 base Windows 7 hangs frequently](https://superuser.com/questions/402185/using-an-ssd-with-no-ahci-ich7-base-windows-7-hangs-frequently/880517#880517)

These all concern SSDs causing Windows to freeze.  What brought them to light is that a user posted an [identical answer](https://superuser.com/a/880516/364367) to all three questions.  Which raises several questions:

- Should any of these questions be duplicates?
- Is the answer appropriate in each case?
- Does the AHCI issue refer to the same thing as SATA emulation (in which case the answer would be a duplicate of existing answers on several of the questions).